# WPF control similar to scroll bar

Tags: wpf, mvvm, scrollbar

I have a string array. Each array element has some content. I need a horizontal scroll bar or anything similar below the window. On clicking next or previous button, array elements needs to be displayed in a textbox accordingly. Something like paging. But I am unable to find any such control. I need to perform this in WPF and MVVM pattern.

Else i'll have to put two buttons and implement the functionality on its click events. But I would not get the scroll bar effect.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for. What "content" is stored in each array element? Is it large portions of string that you want to display in a multiline TextBlock/TextBox or what? Provide more info and some code of what you have tried.

Comment: I think a view model with a collection and selected index should work. Buttons can trigger increment and decrement of index and you can use the collection.Count and selected index to style your own scroll bar visual.

Comment: Yeah, we don't do product recommendations.  Either find one, or create a UserControl and slap all the UI logic you need to get it working in the codebehnd.

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmpowerobjects/archive/2013/02/19/wpf-paging-control-for-wpf-applications.aspx) is worth checking out.